# When accessing a C++ variable how is its content resolved?

Tags: c++, memory

When accessing a variable in C++, how is its content resolved?

Is it possible for the OS to remap the variable to a different address without affecting its logical address? Is it possible to have 2 variables pointing to the same logical address in 2 different processes?

Comment: yes, but the OS shouldn't let this happen.

Comment: By "logical address" do you mean in the virtual memory address space? If yes, than the answer is yes to both your questions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it's absolutely possible for the OS to move variables around in memory.  Virtually all modern computers use [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), in which each process believes that it has access to the machine's full address space.  Whenever a memory read or write occurs, though, the address is translated from the virtual address in the process's address space to some physical address in the computer's real address space.  The operating system can change these mappings as it sees fit, possibly by moving the blocks of memory around, or by temporarily writing them out to disk, etc.  This allows multiple processes to each use more memory than is available on the system, since the OS can move blocks of memory in and out of RAM transparently without the process being able to detect this.

One advantage of using virtual memory is that two processes can each use the same virtual address without conflicting with one another.  For example, two processes might each use address 0xCAFEBABE, and each sees its own copy.  However, when the processes read or write this value, the address will get translated to different physical addresses, and so each can have its own copy.  Many OSes actually provide functionality to allow processes to share memory if they want, or for many processes with similar pieces of data (say, a shared library) to have different virtual addresses that map to the same physical address.

Because C++ directly accesses the machine's underlying memory, any time a variable is read or written in C++, the OS might trap the instruction, page in the physical memory into which the read or write occurs, and then restore control to the program.  This isn't really a feature of C++ as much as the hardware's memory system.

In short - programs work with **virtual addresses**, which the OS maps to **physical addresses** in a way that ensures that each process thinks it has total ownership of the memory system.  C++ programs use this system by default because they're using the underlying hardware.

Comment: @davka- I'm currently in an OS course and spent 12 hours yesterday coding up a simple virtual memory system. :-)  It helps to have it fresh in your mind!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing C++ and OS-specific concepts here. As far as C++ is concerned, there is only one process running in the system and all variables belong to that process. However, most modern OSes use a virtual memory system so that each process gets its own address space, and there are usually OS-specific functions to share memory between processes. One common way of doing this is to use memory-mapped files so that multiple processes can map the same file to their own address spaces and access the same content.